# How can I save a corresponding value in a row after I separate data from another column?

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv, numpy

to add my last question. I want to separate values from one columns, and make them into separate lists. When I do that how can I save the corresponding values from another column?

Example:

depth: 90, 88, 56, 33, 22, 5

Corresponding Irrad Values: 0.01, 0.03, 0.02, 0.02, 0.04, 0.005

So in the row, there is 90 and 0.01, 88 and 0.03, and so on..

I want to separate my depth data based on certain criteria. When I do so how can I save the corresponding value in the same row that I decide to keep.

My Last Question:

[How can I sort through a range in a csv file in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42460458/how-can-i-sort-through-a-range-in-a-csv-file-in-python/42462350#42462350)

My Current Code:

```
import csv
import numpy as np
from collections import defaultdict

columns = defaultdict(list) # each value in each column is appended to a list

with open('C:\\Users\\AdamStoer\\Documents\\practicedata2.csv') as file:

reader = csv.DictReader(file,delimiter=',') # read rows into a dictionary format

def split_my_list(column_data): # here I am splitting my depth data into a dictonary...I split the values from each key into a seperate list
    group =0
    temp = []
    splited_list = {}
    lengh = len(column_data)

    for i in range(lengh):
        if not i == lengh-1:
            if column_data[i] > column_data[i+1]:
                temp.append(column_data[i])
                columns['irrad2'].append(row['sci_ocr504i_irrad2'])
            else:
                temp.append(column_data[i])
                group +=1
                splited_list.update({str(group):temp})
                temp = []
        else:
            if column_data[i] < column_data[-2]:
                temp.append(column_data[i])
                group +=1
                splited_list.update({str(group):temp})
                break
            else:
                group +=1
                splited_list.update({str(group):[[i]]})
                break
    return splited_list

for row in reader: # right here I am sorting the value based on criteria
    r = float(row['roll'])
    p = float(row['pitch'])
    if 0.21 <= p <= 0.31:
            if -0.06 <= r <= 0.06:
                columns['i_depth'].append(row['i_depth'])
                columns['irrad2'].append(row['sci_ocr504i_irrad2'])

depth= columns['i_depth'] 
split_depth = split_my_list(depth) #I split my data here
irrad = columns['irrad2']


lst = []
for depthvalues in split_depth.values(): #i make seperate lists here and do my main math here
    print (depthvalues)
    depthlst = depthvalues
    depthfirst = depthlst[0]
    depthlast = depthlst[-1]

    print (depthfirst + " " + depthlast)
```

I want to do a similar thing with the irrad values but they are not split into a lists like depth, they are still in one big list. So they wont correspond with the depth values I need.

```
irradlst = columns['irrad2']
irradfirst = irradlst[0]
irradlast = irradlst[-1]
```

Comment: It would be helpful to see as sample of your file.  If it consists of neat rows and columns you could load it into a `numpy` array or `pandas` dataframe.  It might be easier to work with in that form. Otherwise, I'd suggest showing a sample of the resulting dictionary.  It's easier to see data than to read code.  I haven't read your previous question.